# Is it possible to create an Android app to change the outgoing greeting for voicemail to an mp3 file?

Tags: android, telephony, voicemail

If not, are there any work-arounds that are simple?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create an Android app to change the outgoing greeting for voicemail to an mp3 file?

No. It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using for your voicemail if you are using carrier voicemail then you would have to talk with them and my guess is they might already be trying to do that. There may be a workaround with google voice but I doubt it.